# Unable to set abiFilter using kotlin dsl

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

After updating android gradle plugin from 4.0.3 to 4.1.0, I am not able to set abiFilter in kotlin DSL.

Getting following error.

`Val cannot be reassigned`

Answer (score 11):

Guess this will be more idiomatic than other current answers,

```
    ndk {
        abiFilters += listOf("armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64")
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

able to add by doing as following

```
abiFilters.add("armeabi")
abiFilters.add("mips")
```

Answer (score 4):

Use like this

```
defaultConfig {
     ndk {
          abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
          abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
         }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can add abi list like this**

```
defaultConfig {
    ndk {
    abiFilters.addAll(arrayOf("armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"))
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).